# C# Why is Linq crashing about a Null if the value is not null?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a simple three table reference. It looks plain enough. The associations there are created in the DBML. They are not actually foreign keys in the table definition. Why? That's a long story. Trust me when I say, I've fought that battle and lost.

[image]

When I attempt to add a new FileType record using LINQ, it crashes with the error: ***Cannot insert the value NULL into column Id, table FileType.***

```
            _fileType = new FileType()
            {
                Id = def.ID, // This is the integer "1"
                Name = def.Name,
                FileCategoryId = def.Category.ID,
                DateLabel = def.DateLabel,
                FileNamePrefix = def.Prefix,
                FolderName = def.Folder,
                CreateInspection = 0
            };

            try
            {
                dc.FileTypes.InsertOnSubmit(_fileType);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            }
```

But if you'll notice the code, Id is being set. I've checked the value and it is not null. It is an integer. What am I missing or doing wrong??

I did check to make sure that the FileCategory record of the correct ID exists. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Is it perhaps an auto-increment field? In that case, you wouldn't have to set ID for inserting a record.

Comment: No. I made sure that it is just a field. It has no identity specification defined for it. I use it like a key, but in reality, it's just an integer. With Management studio, I can set and alter the field at-will.

Comment: Can you please show us the T-SQL that is being generated from this code?

Comment: So the FileType is just a normal table without any constraints? Like 
create table FileType
(
 ID int not null primary key,
...
 CreateInspection int not null
)

Comment: Also, can you please tell us what the ModelGeneratedPattern property is set to for the Id column?

Comment: In your table mapping, is the field marked as 'Auto Generated Value' in the Properties pane? I've had insert/update issues with that before...

Comment: Can you show your definition class of FileType?

Comment: Tieson T: That was it! Somehow that setting was turned ON even though it is not auto-generated in the tables. Make that an official answer so that I can approve it and give you some kudos points!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In your table mapping, is the field marked as 'Auto Generated Value'
>   in the Properties pane? I've had insert/update issues with that
>   before... – Tieson T. Mar 7 at 6:52

I would give him the props for this, but he left this as a comment, and not an official answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen something like this before.

It happens when you only assign the 'id' and not the related object.

Try the following:

```
new FileType
{
  FileCategory = def.Category,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I seem to forget this every time. Thanks for the reminder. :)